# Fundamental group of intersection of two codimension=2 complements

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

$X$ is a smooth manifold.    $Y_1\subset X$ and $Y_2\subset X$ are both complements of a finite collection of real codimension=2 (transversal intersecting) submanifolds. Suppose  $Y:=Y_1 \cap Y_2$  is also a complement of codimension=2 (transversal intersecting) submanifolds.    If we know  $\pi_1(Y_1)$ and $\pi_1(Y_2)$,  then do we know their generators generate $\pi_1(Y)$?

From Alexander duality, we have this for $H_1$. However, I couldn't figure out how this lead to fundamental groups.

Comment: Can you be a little more precise what you mean by "their generators generate $\pi_1(Y)$? Maybe you want the map $\pi_1(Y) \to \pi_1(Y_1) \times \pi_1(Y_2)$ to be an embedding?

Comment: I'm hoping something like a surjective map from the free product of $\pi_1(Y_1)\times \pi_1(Y_2)$ to $\pi_1(Y).$

Comment: If your two manifolds "link", I don't think $\pi_1(Y_i)$ has to be a subgroup of $\pi_1 Y$.   I'm thinking of $Y_1$ being a trefoil exterior and $Y_2$ being a singular fiber of the Seifert fibering.